# Retrieve Dictionary value from GridView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, dictionary

I've been trying to do this for a long time now without success.

I am trying to store a Dictionary in a GridView in WPF. I am able to store the Keys/Values, but unable to get the values of specific keys. For example, in the example below I would like to retrieve the value for the key "1" (which is "4"). No success yet with TryGetValue.

This is my code:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            McDataGrid.ItemsSource = files.Keys;
        }

Dictionary<Files, string> files = new Dictionary<Files, string>();

public class Files
{
    public string File { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }               
}

private void AddFilesList(string addsrc, string addduration, string addstatus, string path)
        {
            files.Add(new Files
            {
                File = addsrc,
                Duration = addduration,
                Status = addstatus

            }, path
               );

            DataGrid.Items.Refresh();
        }

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddFilesList("1", "2", "3", "4");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
    foreach (KeyValuePair<Files, string> pair in files)
    {
        if (pair.Key.File == "1")
        { 
           pair.Value// This will be return 4
        }
    }
```

Comment: @user1751280 : You can check my code. Try it and tell me, Is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void OnDataGridSelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var value = files[DataGrid.SelectedItem];
    }
```

Comment: I would like to get the value without the object being selected. Also your solution gives me compile error: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectedItem.get'".

Comment: Your solution does not work. Compile error: cannot convert from 'object' to 'WpfApplication7.MainWindow.Files'.

Comment: var value = files[(Files)DataGrid.SelectedItem];